# Firebase rules when user log out 'Missing or insufficient permissions. Error: Missing or insufficient permissions'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, logout, firebase-security

**Error :**

> 'Error with profile listener: Missing or insufficient permissions. Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.'

My app is a project manager built using Reactjs, Redux, Firebase.
Could you tell me why it gives this error when the user logs out and how to solve it?

**My rules:**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  // Match any {project} document in the 'projects' collection
    match /projects/{project} {
     // Allow signed in users to read write projects
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null; 
    }
    // Match any {user} document in the 'users' collection
    match /users/{user} {
     // Allow users to signup and create an account
      allow create;
      // Allow signed in users to read project details - who create project and when)
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      // Allow signed in user to update his info only if signed in id == user document id
      allow update, delete: if request.auth.uid == user;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your rules (Line 6 of the code snippet) specify that only authenticated users can read or write data

Comment: Can you post the code sample of the logout? What language is the client written in? Can you post the error stack trace to make sure the problem is the logout and not something else?

Comment: I have added that my app built using Reactjs, Redux, Firebase. I'm a newbie so I can't get what do you mean with _the error stack trace_?

Answer (score 2):

If this happens when you log out, that means you still have an [`onSnapshot` listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) attached to a collection that requires a user to be authenticated. When you log out, that listener becomes invalid, and thus the security rules reject it.

To get rid of the message, remove all such listeners before the user logs out. In your specific case, it seems to be a problem with the "profile listener".

Comment: Can you give an example? I can't see where such a listener is added, so I don't know how to remove it. I am using angular, ts and `AngularFireAuth` and the signout method just calls `this.angularFireAuth.auth.signOut();`

Answer (score 0):

When you logout any existing subscribes will still be subscribed and you will get that error. You can unsubscribe before logout or send the user to another page and logout from there. When you send a the user to another page the subscribes should be garbage collected. Thats how it works in angular components at least, not sure about react.