# "Insufficient permissions" error when signing out of Firebase React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

My project is in React/Firebase. I get an "Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions." when logging out of it. There are read/write rules in place so it makes sense that I am getting the error.

I think it has to do with how the `onSnapshot` listeners are getting detached, as per:
[Firebase rules when user log out 'Missing or insufficient permissions. Error: Missing or insufficient permissions'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599250/firebase-rules-when-user-log-out-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-error-mi)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in detaching them -- there are 6 snapshot listeners in the project, and (I think) I've narrowed it down to the following component provides User info:

```
const UserProvider = props => {
  const [{ user }, setUser] = useState({ user: null });
  const unsubscribeRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
      if (user) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(user);

        unsubscribeRef.current = userRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          setUser({ user: { uid: snapshot.id, ...snapshot.data() } });
        });
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribeRef.current();
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>{props.children}</UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Before, I was just attaching the unsubscribe variable directly to the `userRef.onSnapshot` bit, with no luck -- which is why I tried `useRef` here. I wonder if I need to attach somehow the point when signOut is called? No other examples of React/Firebase apps seem to use that. Lastly, I don't understand why but the return statement inside the `useEffect` never seems to be reached here.

If it helps, this is the `Authentication` component:

```
const Authentication = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
      if (userAuth) {
        if (history.location.pathname === ROUTES.SIGN_IN)
          history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
      } else {
        history.push(ROUTES.SIGN_IN);
      }
    });
  }, [history]);

  return null;
};
```

Edit:
These are the rules in Firestore:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if getUserData().admin == true;
    }

    function getUserData() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure what else would be relevant here. Upon signing out, the user is routed back to the SignIn page which doesn't use anything from the database.

App() is structured like so:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Router>
        <Authentication />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
          <Route path="/forgot" component={ForgotPasswordView} />

          <CatalogProvider>
            <Route path="/" component={Main} />
          </CatalogProvider>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

And Main contains the rest of the working parts of the app.

Comment: Please edit the question to show all relevant code, especially the database query that fails with the error you're showing.  Since it's a permission error, also show the security rules that are rejecting the query.  We need to be able to match the **specific** query to the **specific** rules.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated my question, hope it's sufficient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to realize is that `onAuthStateChanged` will give you a null user object when the user signs out.  Your code doesn't seem to handle that case.

Another thing to realize is that when the user signs out, if any active listener on a query would become invalid due to security rules (for example, request.auth becomes null), then the listener will be cut off with a permission error.  You should remove all persistent listeners on queries that depend on authentication **before** signing out, or simply accept that the errors will happen and the listeners automatically removed.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Do you have a suggestion for handling the null user object returned by `onAuthStateChanged`?

Comment: At least check it and do nothing, if that's what you want?  You decide what happens when the user signs out.